# JavaScript Sequental operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

What is the best way/pattern to perform sequental operations in JS(NodeJS)?
E.g. Create folder->copy file->edit file->etc.
This is stand-alone app, so thread-blocking oprations is ok(Sync).

Comment: Just do sync calls then. I'm not aware of any design pattern for this. Seems you just want to write the code that you've described and that's it.

Comment: Not really sure what the question is here.  If it's a stand-alone app, then just use the `sync` versions of the fs operations like you see to already know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't.  Get in the habit of writing async code in node *everywhere*, even if it doesn't need to be.  It's just good practice, prevents refactoring a bunch of stuff in the future, and with modern JS it's simple to write:

```
import { mkdir, copyFile } from 'fs/promises';

async function createThing() {
    await mkdir('/path/to/dir');
    await copyFile(src, dest);
    ...
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely no reason to avoid sync versions of fs operations when it's a stand-alone utility app, not a server (which is what the OP says it is).  Using the asynchronous versions, when there is no advantage just makes the code more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @jfriend00 - "more complicated than necessary" - LMAO.  Adding the word `await` makes it soooo hard to read.  And there is *always* an advantage in that it is zero extra effort, often non-trivial refactoring effort, and we as devs *suck* at predicting what they're going to use things for in the future.  Just get in the habit and save your future self some pain.

Comment: What's the difference between await mkdir() and mkdirSync()?

Comment: It makes the calling code be asynchronous and the caller of that code too.  Now it has to be awaited.  If it's a callback to a `.map()`, or something like that then you have to use `Promise.all()` and so on...  If this is a file that other event triggered code could also access, then you have to worry about multiple paths of code contending for the same file, etc...

Comment: While `async/await` is certainly easier than what we had before, it is not as simple as synchronous I/O in a number of ways when synchronous I/O is ok to use.  If you want to never use synchronous I/O everywhere, then feel free, but for what the OP is doing (a single user utility application), I'd recommend synchronous I/O.

Comment: @DanielRay - `await fs.promises.mkdir()` suspends the current `async` function and immediately returns an unresolved promise back to the caller.  If the caller isn't awaiting that promise, the caller will continue to execute other code (which can be an advantage or a disadvantage depending upon circumstances).  Similarly, other events can be processed by the event loop (timers, networking events, I/O completion, etc...).  If you use `fs.mkdirSync()`, it blocks everything so nothing executes until that function finishes.  It forces serial execution of everything.

Comment: @DanielRay - Note that `await fs.mkdir()` is neither fish nor fowl as the `await` doesn't do anything because `fs.mkdir()` does not return a promise (it doesn't return anything).  To use `await`, use `await fs.promises.mkdir()`.  Also, error handling is different for all three versions.  `fs.promises.mkdir()` rejects the promise it returned.  `fs.mkdir()` sends the `err` argument to the callback you provide it and `fs.mkdirSync()` throws an exception.

Comment: Of course, if you have a specific desire for parallel execution of I/O operations, then the asynchronous I/O options will provide that.  The question here was specifically about how to achieve sequenced I/O, not parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `async`/`await` for sequential, asynchronous operations. No need to write sync code that you'll regret later. Also, depending on the application, you might get trivial speedup opportunities by doing things concurrently.